# Route Naming in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
**Working Routes**
<Route path="/moversng" component={AppMoverLandingPage} />
<Route path="/movers-ng/dashboard/login" component={AppMoverLogin} />
<Route path="/movers-ng/dashboard" component={AppDashboard} />
<Route path="/movers-ng/manage-users" component={AppManageUsers} />
```

```
**What I wanted but not working**
<Route path="/moversng" component={AppMoverLandingPage} />
<Route path="/moversng/dashboard/login" component={AppMoverLogin} />
<Route path="/moversng/dashboard" component={AppDashboard} /> - *Worked*
<Route path="/moversng/dashboard/manage-users" component={AppManageUsers} /> - *Not working*
```

Question:
Are they conventional ways of route naming against your folder name?
From what I wanted routes, with those naming, the component/page will not render but retained the previous page.

What am I doing wrongly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `exact` to your routes, without it the routes are being considered child routes:

```
<Route path="/moversng" exact component={AppMoverLandingPage} />
<Route path="/moversng/dashboard/login" exact component={AppMoverLogin} />
<Route path="/moversng/dashboard" exact component={AppDashboard} /
<Route path="/moversng/dashboard/manage-users" exact component={AppManageUsers}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try work with **exact**
for example:

```
<Route path="/" component={Home} exact/>
<Route path="/about" component={About} />
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
```